# RXJS merge different observables, but ignore all but active

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have multiple buttons, each emitting its own Subject. Like:

```
btn1 => click => one$.next();
btn2 => click => two$.next();
btn3 => click => three$.next();
```

Then, I have corresponding Observables:

```
processOne = one$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => timer(0, 1000)));
processTwo = two$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => timer(0, 1000)))
processThree = three$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => timer(0, 1000)))

merge(processOne, processTwo, processThree).subscribe(console.log);
```

In the code above, only one$ or two$ or three$ are ignored if the corresponding subject emits. But what I want is basically not to start a timer for two$ and three$ if one$ is already active, and vice versa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single subject, but pass the "id" of the clicked button.  Then, define the different "process observables" in a map, that you can lookup based on the id.  Finally, use a single `exhaustMap` on the subject, which will ignore all other button clicks while processing is ongoing:

```
btn1 => click => click$.next(1);
btn2 => click => click$.next(2);
btn3 => click => click$.next(3);
```

```
processes = {
   1: timer(0, 1000),   // Assuming these are not identical.
   2: timer(0, 1000),   // Otherwise you don't need to
   3: timer(0, 1000),   // define them like this.
};
```

```
activeProcess$ = this.click$.pipe(
   exhaustMap(id => processes[id])
);
```